# Hive select query with current date in where clause

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am new to hive. I have a table like following:

```
  EntriesRunDate (
     id string,
     run_date string
  );
```

In the above table a entry will be processed when its associated run_date is today's date (where run_date is in YYYYMMDD format).

To select such rows, I have written following hive query:

```
 select * from EntriesRunDate where run_date = (select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'YYYYMMDD'));
```

But while running above query, I am getting following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Unsupported SubQuery Expression ''YYYYMMDD'': Only SubQuery expressions that are top level conjuncts are allowed
```

Though I think there is a way to do this by setting a variable in command line and re-using it within hive, but I want to do everything in hive. I am not sure also if it's doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a sub-query and can compare the value directly as

```
where run_date = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_date),'yyyyMMdd')
```

or using `date_format`

```
where run_date = date_format(current_date,'yyyyMMdd')
```